# React - Inline dynamic component style not being updated onMouseOver and onMouseOut events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the below code is executed in my app, the button has a white background and hovering over it changes nothing. However, console logs do show that the onMouseOver and onMouseOut events are triggering and change the value of initialState from false to true and back again.

```js
const GetQuoteButton = (props) => {

 let initialState = false;

 function onMouseOver() {
  return initialState = true;
 }

 function onMouseOut() {
  return initialState = false;
 }

 return (
  <button
   onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
   onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
   style={{ backgroundColor: initialState ? props.color : 'white' }}
   onClick={props.changeQuote}
   className="GetQuoteButton">
   Change Quote
  </button>
 )

}

ReactDOM.render(<GetQuoteButton color="red" />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a functional component. It does not know anything about state. Your component is only re-rendered when the props change. React has no way of knowing that your component needs re-rendered when `initialState` changes.

To solve this, you need to use a class with state:

```js
class GetQuoteButton extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { hover: false };
      }
    
      onMouseOver() {
        this.setState({ hover: true });
      }
    
      onMouseOut() {
        this.setState({ hover: false });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <button
            onMouseOver={() => this.onMouseOver()}
            onMouseOut={() => this.onMouseOut()}
            style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.hover ? this.props.color : "white" }}
            onClick={this.props.changeQuote}
            className="GetQuoteButton"
          >
            Change Quote
          </button>
        );
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<GetQuoteButton color="red" />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was fairly certain this was the cause of my issue. Issue resolved!

Answer (score 0):

what is happening?

1° Your onMouseEvents are just changing a variable, and react does not know that it needs a rerender with this variable update.

2° You are using a stateless component you have two options here:
    Either change this component to a state one, or change the initial state to come from props, and do the setState on your parent component

Example should work:
Doing the setState to change a variable state/value will force rerender on this component and will update the ui with the changed variable

```js
import React from 'react';

class GetQuoteButton extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = { initialState: false };
}

onMouseOver=()=> {
    this.setState({initialState:true})
}

onMouseOut =()=>{
    this.setState({initialState:false})
}

render() {
    const {initialState}=this.state
    const {color,changeQuote}=this.props

    return <button
   onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
   onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
   style={{ backgroundColor: initialState ? 
                     color : 'white' }}
   onClick={changeQuote}
   className="GetQuoteButton">
   Change Quote
  </button>
}
}
 
export default GetQuoteButton
```